# How can I adjust inputfield rows to a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, binary, decimal

I´m programming a math game where user has to transform a decimal digit into binary digit by dividing with 2. I wanted to adjust the rows to the length of the binary digit (e.g. 8 is 1000, so it shall only generate 4 rows to transform digit in a binary digit). I use display() to generate a digit from 1-31, deciToBin() to convert decimal to binary and createBoxes() to adjust rows to the length of binary digit.
**But it only works for the first round. If I continue playing there are more rows than the length of the binary digit or less rows than the length of the binary digit.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two observations:

- I'm not seeing anywhere that you're ever setting any `inputboxes.style.visibility` to `hidden`. Seems like they should perhaps all get hidden before each new number sets up its boxes (kind of a "reset"). Otherwise, the way it is now, if the first `number` is 30 you'll display 5 boxes, and if the next number is 1, you'll still display five boxes, because the last four are still `visibility:visible`.
- I think you could replace `createBoxes(deciToBin(number).length)` with `createBoxes((number).toString(2).length)` and just get rid of `deciToBin()`. `toString()` is standard and fast.

UPDATE: Here's an alternate `createBoxes` that would set all `inputboxes` every time there's a new number:

```js
// untested code
function createBoxes(value) {
  for (var i = 0, len = inputboxes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i < value) {
      inputboxes[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      inputboxes[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer. I understood your solution. The problem is, in my CSS file the inputboxes are already hidden. They only get visible with the createBoxes()-function. Do you have an idea how or where to reset the inputboxes?

Comment: The CSS hides the inputboxes on load, but not afterward because setting `inputboxes.style.visibility` will have higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the original CSS.

Adding an alternate createBoxes() to my answer above.